# Will changes made in a remote Github repo be reflected locally in Rstudio?

Tags: r, github, package

I’ve made a package on RStudio and I successfully put it on Github. I just have to add a README file. I acknowledge that this should be the easiest possible thing to do, but I’m pretty new at git and still learning.

I’m wondering if adding a README on the Github repository would be reflected in the local branch in Rstudio? If possible, I don’t want to have some files added on the Github repo and not have them locally on RStudio. Or if I’d be better off creating a README locally in RStudio and then pushing it to Github?

If the latter, would anyone have any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: If the latter, then you have pretty much already laid out the necessary steps.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Sometimes it is useful to step back a little.  What you ask here is orthogonal to RStudio and simply about the nature of (distributed) git repos. So yes, you can always change one and _then need to push or pull as needed_ to propagate the change.  It is not like, say, Dropbox, where it 'just happens'.

Comment: Thanks, @mkrieger1, I guess I basically answered my own Q then haha. Another silly follow-up due to my lack of specificity in the initial question: Is there any specific way to create a README in RStudio?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for your response, too. So I guess I could create a README in Github and then “pull” it locally to RStudio.

Comment: Absolutely!  You could use the web UI at GitHub to preview what you are writing, comitt and a pull (if the remote is correctly associated) will bring it to you.  Where you could it alter it further and pushed the changes back for GitHub to display and serve.  Rinse and repeat a million times.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel This is incredibly helpful. Thank you very much!